Would you use a sharkbite coupling on a hot/cold copper joint or would soldering be better?
moderately experienced DIYer and just put in a new tub that's a bit deeper than the old one and need to raise the tub spout a couple inches.   The two joint methods I have experience with and equipment for are solder or sharkbite.   I know plumbers often use crimp but I never have so probably not going to go that way for a first try.  Previous solder joints aren't the prettiest but they've held, and there's plenty of room to do it here.   Cost for one fitting isn't an issue so would a sharkbite fitting (properly prepped) be just as good and not have to deal with the hassle and light experience for soldering?   Or do folks not recommend them for hot/cold copper lines long term?
